# curve_fit() with 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, scipy-optimize

I want to do a least-square fitting to my (m x n) arrays of X and Y as an example shown below

```
def func(x,m,c):
  lsq=(m*x) + c
  return lsq 

xdata=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
ydata=[[10,20,30],[10,20,30],[10,20,30]]

coeff, var = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata)
```

The one easy solution is to use the `for` loop

```
for i in range(len(xdata)):
  xdata_ = xdata[i]
  ydata_ = ydata[i]
  coeff, var = curve_fit(func,xdata_,ydata_)
```

But to use a `for` loop is a very slow process because in the actual case the array size is 6000 x 6000. I have ten arrays of the size 6000 x 6000. From these ten arrays for every element (36000000), I need to do the least square fitting. My ydata is fixed as shown below. Now, xdata is every single element from the ten arrays.

```
xdata =  [[array1[0],array2[0],...array10[0]],[array1[1],array2[1],...array10[1]],...[array1[36000000],array2[36000000],...array10[36000000]]]
ydata =  [[1e6,2e6,...10e6],[1e6,2e6,...10e6],...[1e6,2e6,...10e6]]
```

Is there any way to load above xdata and ydata into the curve_fit function without loop? Thanks.

Comment: Could you describe the X and Y matrices a bit more? The way you're doing it implies that each row of your X and Y matrices is an independent observation you want to fit for (i.e. you want M=6000 independent fits)?

Comment: My xdata is  (36000000,10). From ten arrays (each of size 6k x 6k) I want to fit leastsquare for every elements (from ten arrays) against ydata=[1e6,2e6,3e6,4e6,5e6,6e6,7e6,8e6,9e6,10e6]. For instance take 0th element from every ten arrays and fit against ydata, then take 1st element from every ten arrays and fit against ydata...like this upto 36000000th element from ten arrays and fit against the same ydata.

Comment: So there's 36e6 separate curve fits with independent fit parameters that you want to do, or are the parameters consistent across the 36e6 instances? If the former, I think you're stuck with a for loop, though you could parallelize it, and if the latter you can simply reshape.